# Dynamic Grouped Checkbox list with respect to Label

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have an Array , for E.g

```
Data: Array<any> = [
    { name: 'Pear', value: 'pear' ,label : Fruit},
    { name: 'Plum', value: 'plum' , label : Fruit},
    { name: 'Kiwi', value: 'kiwi' , label : Fruit},
    { name: 'Brinjal', value: 'Brinjal' ,label : Vegetable},
    { name: 'Cabbage', value: 'Cabbage' ,label : Vegetable}
  ];
```

i want to display this as

```
Label - Vegetable
Checbox 1 = brinjal , Checkbox 2 = Cabbage
```

(Checkbox will be actual checkbox)

```
Label - Fruit
Checbox 1 = Pear, Checkbox 2 = Plum ,Checkbox 3 = kiwi
```

or an array like this

```
{
   "label1":{
      "checkboxname":"value",
      "checkboxname":"value"
   },
   "label2":{
      "checkboxname":"value"
   }
}
```

how do i do this in Angular or Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.reduce()` to sort your array by a distinct label value

```
myArray = this.data.reduce(function (r, a) {
    r[a.label] = r[a.label] || [];
    r[a.label].push(a);
    return r;
}, Object.create(null));
```

and then you can create a list of checkboxes like that:

```
<label *ngFor="let checkboxes of sortedCheckboxes | keyvalue">
    {{checkboxes.key}}<br/>
    <label *ngFor="let checkbox of sortedCheckboxes[checkboxes.key]"> 
      <input type="checkbox" value="{{checkbox.value}}" /> {{checkbox.name}}
    </label>
  <br><br>
</label>
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-td3bzq)

Comment: im getting the Result in console.log , but im getting this Error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]"

Comment: It's hard to say what is wrong without seeing any of your code.

Comment: Thankx a Lot , it worked .. PRoblem was with the NgFor tag not placed Properly ,, can u also updated the code on stackblitz  with Checbox Required Validation and Max checkbox selected must be 3 ,,in Form Control .. Thankx in Advances